# Mysql select result in one currency

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have to create a reports in one currency. I need to do query in MySQL without using PHP process. but unable to figure it out.
There is a table called currency_exchange_rate table as follows, (exchange rate in LKR to other currency).this table is updating like one record for each currency in LKR in every month

exchange_rates

```
id  currency_id  start_date  exchange_rate
1     5           2017-01-2      155
2     4           2017-01-3      25
3     6           2017-01-3      53
4     5           2017-02-1      156
5     4           2017-02-1      24
6     6           2017-02-1      54
```

There is a project table as follows

```
 pro_id  name      value      currency_id  status_id  owner_id  date
 1       studio1   500        5              1          44      2017-01-20
 2       lotus     120        5              1          42      2017-01-21
 3       auro      300        4              2          45      2017-01-21
 4       studio2   400        6              1          44      2017-01-22
 5       holland   450        4              3          46      2017-02-05
 6       studio3   120        4              3          47      2017-02-06
 7       studio4   400        6              3          48      2017-02-06
```

how to generate reports in one currency(DKK but exchange rate in LKR) like status wise,monthly total, total by owner, etc..

and we have to consider currency id,currency to be convert and exchange rate for the month for those currency types to get relevant value for project row.

hope you are clear about my scenario. your help is much appreciated.

I don't need every report. just want a sql for convert values in project table using exchange rates table or status wise report as follows

```
status_id  value_in_one_currency
1          xxxx
2          xxxx
3          xxxx
```

Comment: Your question seems too broad, please try to simplify it. You can break it down into multple questions and ask.

Comment: @cdaiga I don't need every report. just want a sql for convert values in project table using exchange rates table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I finalize:
I took currency_id=5 as the final currency to be converted

```
SELECT A.*,C.exchange_rate AS DKK,D.exchange_rate AS LKR, (order_value * D.exchange_rate /C.exchange_rate ) AS `converted_value`
FROM projects A 
LEFT JOIN exchange_rates C ON  (DATE_FORMAT(C.start_date,'%Y-%m')=DATE_FORMAT(A.`date`,'%Y-%m') AND C.currency_id=5)
LEFT JOIN exchange_rates D ON  DATE_FORMAT(D.start_date,'%Y-%m')=DATE_FORMAT(A.`date`,'%Y-%m') AND D.currency_id=A.currency_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.status_id, A.`value` * B.exchange_rate `value_in_one_currency`
FROM project A JOIN exchange_rates B
ON A.currency_id=C.currency_id 
   AND DATE_FORMAT(A.`date`,'%m-%Y')=DATE_FORMAT(B.`start_date`,'%m-%Y');
```

See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) for some insight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cdaiga but you have missd some points value_in_LKR=value*exchange_rate_for_the_month; value_in_one_currency_DKK=value_in_LKR/DKK_exchange_rate_for_the_month; Any way your answer helps me to find a solution for this. need your  optimization fro following answer

Comment: please take a look at my answer @cdaiga

Comment: Fill out the values for `xxxx`